# Why a cone/parabolic set for the nontangential maximal function?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, heat-equation, harmonic-functions

Suppose $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Then the Dirichlet BVP for the Laplace equation $\Delta u = 0$ in the upper-half plane $\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ with boundary value $f$ can be solved by convolution with the Poisson kernel $u = P_y * f$, where the boundary condition is satisfied in the sense that if $u$ is defined by this convolution, then
$$
\lim_{\substack{(z,y)\to(x,0)\\(z,y)\in \Gamma_x^\theta}} u(z,y) = f(x)
$$
for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$, where $\theta>0$ and $\Gamma_x^\theta$ is the cone with vertex at $(x,0)$ with aperture angle determined by the parameter $\theta$:
$$
\Gamma_x^\theta = \{(z,y)\in\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}_{>0}: |z-x|<\theta y\}.
$$
I have gone through the proof of this using the associated maximal function estimate, and I have heard similar statements can be proved for more general elliptic equations of the form $Lu = 0$.

One also has a similar situation for the heat equation $u_t - \Delta u = 0$, $u(x,t):\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}_{>0} \to \mathbb{R}$ with Cauchy data $u(x,0) = f(x)\in\mathbb{R}^d$. In this case the boundary condition is satisfied with another nontangential limit: if $u$ is given by convolution of the Cauchy data $f$ and the Gauss-Weierstrass kernel, then
$$
\lim_{\substack{(z,t)\to(x,0)\\(z,t)\in P_x}} u(z,y) = f(x)
$$
for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$, where $\theta>0$ and $P_x$ is the parabolic set
$$
P_x= \{(z,t)\in\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}_{>0}: |z-x|<\sqrt{t}\}.
$$

My question: how does one determine that the sets $\Gamma_x^\theta$ and $P_x$ are the right ones to consider for establishing nontangential convergence? For the Laplace equation there is conformal symmetry, and for the heat equation there is a spacetime square-dilation symmetry, so *a posteriori* the cone/parabolic sets seem to match the equations. Also, for the Laplace equation one has the exterior cone condition satisfied on this boundary, which I suspect is related. But I would like to know how one comes up with them in the first place.

Comment: It seems you waited less than three hours from posting to MSE to posting the same question here.  I don't think that this is a good idea, as people may not be so eager to help.  This question seems (to me, a non-expert in PDEs) to be appropriate for this site, so perhaps you should consider retaining only one instance of the question.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill Noted. I've deleted the MSE instance. As you may have guessed, I wasn't sure if this question was at a level appropriate for MO.

Comment: @GyuEunLee Where one can look up the result for the heat equation?

Comment: @Andrew I'm not sure; I proved it myself as part of a homework exercise, but part of the reason I'm asking is precisely that I'm having trouble finding references treating this result (especially its motivations) in detail. As for the proof itself, it is quite similar to the analogous proof for the Laplace equation.